# After refreshing a dropdown list with new elements it displays with a vertical scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a dropdown list that initially has one element.

```html
<select (click)="loadStuff()">
  <option value="DEFAULT_ELEMENT">DEFAULT</option>
  <option *ngFor="let e of elements" [ngValue]="e">{{ e }}</option>
</select>
```

The drop downlist has a `click` event that loads the dropdown elements if not already loaded:

```js
  public elements = [];

  loadStuff() {
    if (!this.elements.length) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        for (let i=0; i < 10; i++) {
          this.elements.push('element ' + i)
        }
      }, 1000)
    }
  }
```

Now my problem is: when I click the dropdown itself, it initially has one element as expected:

[image]

But after the elements are loaded (while the dropdown is still open) it adds a scroll bar to the elements:

[image]

I then need to click away and back for the list to properly show:

[image]

Here's a working Angular version to showcase the problem: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pgyd1q

Also the same behavious using `jQuery`: http://jsfiddle.net/6j7a3sxn/

How can I prevent that from happening ?

Answer (score 1):

Simply do not fetch data on HTMLSelectElement click... Do it in ngOnInit or in the resolver. Or don't use native select control :)

Comment: I have many elements that need to be loaded on-demand. Loading everything in ngOnInit is not a good option (I already use it to load some 'mandatory' dropdowns). 
Also using my own component would have a great impact on the huge code I have to deal with.

Comment: Maybe something like this? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-724md3

Comment: Unfortunately, this issue is caused by the default select behavior and probably you'll can't do nothing with it, except some weird tricks like unmounting and unmounting element in DOM which will be like a using cannon to kill the fly

Comment: Yes thank you I already have a custom component I use for loading asynchroniously. Now I'd like to avoid impacting the 30+ pages where this problem occurs for me and all the tests I'll need to run after that. replacing "HTMLSelectElement" will be my last resort if no other "simpler" solution can be implemented. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: The possible fix might be fetching data on mouseover event and locking this select during fetch process...

Comment: Yes this seems to be the case (default select behaviour) I was looking for something like preventig the select from openning while the data isn't loaded yet and then opening it when it's done.. but it doesn't seem to be possible

Comment: nice thanks. Is there a way we can automatically open the dropdown after it's been reenabled ?

Comment: it's ugly workaround, but it works: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jeg2c6

however you have to handle closing process and other possible behaviors

Comment: Yes almost.. the dropdown stays open afterwards and can never be closed :) But nice solution nevertheless.. and thank you very much for your time